# Proving $\lim_{\vec{h}\to 0}\frac{\|f(\vec{u}+\vec{h})-f(\vec{u})\|}{\|\vec{h}\|} = \|J_f(\vec{u})\|_{\text{op}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm looking to prove the limit in the title statement for $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ differentiable in the necessary open set, where $\|A\|_{\text{op}}$ is the operator norm. I proceeded as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left|\frac{\|f(\vec u+\vec h) - f(\vec u)\|}{\|\vec h\|} - \|J_f(\vec u)\|_{\text{op}}\right| & = \left|\frac{\|f(\vec u+\vec h)-f(\vec u)\|-\|J_f(\vec u)\|_{\text{op}}\|\vec  h\|}{\|\vec h\|}\right| \\
& \le \left|\frac{\|f(\vec u+\vec h) - f(\vec u)\|-\|J_f(\vec u)\vec h\|}{\|\vec  h\|}\right| \\
& \le \frac{\|f(\vec u+\vec h)-f(\vec u)-J_f(\vec u)\vec h\|}{\|\vec h\|}
\end{aligned}
$$
where we use $\|Av\|\le\|A\|_{\text{op}}\|v\|$ to go from the first line to the second line, and the reverse triangle inequality to go from the second line to the third line. Then by the squeeze theorem we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
0 & \le\lim_{\vec h\to 0}\left|\frac{\|f(\vec u+\vec h)-f(\vec u)\|}{\|\vec h\|} - \|J_f(\vec u)\|_{\text{op}}\right| \\
& \le\lim_{\vec h\to 0}\frac{\|f(\vec u+\vec h)-f(\vec u)-J_f(\vec u)\vec h\|}{\|\vec h\|} \\
& = 0
\end{aligned}
$$
Looks alright, right? Well I realized there's a *tiny* detail: Suppose $z<y$. Then clearly, $x-y<x-z$. **However**, it is not necessarily true that $|x-y|<|x-z|$. This means we can't use the fact that $\|Av\|\le\|A\|_{\text{op}}\|v\|$ to go from the first line to the second line above.

Is this "proof" salvageable? Is what I'm trying to prove even true? If not, what does the limit actually evaluate to?

Comment: It does look alright. But on second thought I think it is false. If $f$ is linear then you are asking whether $$\lim_{\mathbf h\to \mathbf 0 } \frac{\| Ah \| }{\|h\|} =\| A\|_{\mathrm{op}},$$ where $A$ is a matrix. And this is not true: take for example $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$, you'll see that the limit depends on whether we take $\mathbf h= h e_1$ or $h e_2$, that is, the limit does not exist.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro That's a very good point, thanks for letting me know! What, then, does $\frac{\|f(u+h)-f(u)\|}{\|h\|}$ converge to then? It's obvious what it converges to if we let $h$ tend to $0$ linearly (then it converges to the absolute value of the directional derivative), but in general $h$ may not take a linear path to $0$.

Comment: I think that the limit never exists unless the Jacobian matrix is a scalar multiple of the identity.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Yeah I guess you're right, since in different linear directions the limit evaluates to the directional derivative in different directions, which is not always the same (take $f(x,y) = x$ at $(0,0)$ for example). My mistake for not checking it further, and assuming it would have a closed form.

Comment: That argument you posted looks solid, it had fooled me completely.

Comment: It should be $J_f(\vec{h})$.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood: what do you mean?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: The notation $J_f(\vec{h})$ is wrong. The Jacobian acts on displacement vector between the points $x,x+h$ i.e $\vec{h}$, not $\vec{u}$.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood: I disagree. The title is correct as is, it is intended that the point u is identified with its position vector. Writing $Jf(h) $ would make no sense, as $h$ is the dummy variable in the limit.

Comment: That is, $Jf(u) $ here stands for "jacobian at u" the kind of thing that a differential geometer would denote by $\left. df\right|u$.

Comment: I didn't read the comment about the operator norm. I looked at the notation and thought the OP was saying $J_f(\vec{u})$ approximates the change in $f$. But with the operator norm notation it makes sense that the statement is equivalent to my notation $D_uf (\vec{h})$ ( I do some differential geometry). Thank you.